# Incorrect evaluation of a convolution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, convolution

I want to evaluate a convolution for a stripe function and a Gaussian:

```
stripe[x_, d_] := If[EvenQ[Quotient[x, d]], 1, 0]
gaussian[x_, μ_, σ_] = 1/(Sqrt[2 π] σ) Exp[-((x - μ)^2/(2 σ^2))];
Plot[{stripe[τ, 1], gaussian[τ, 0, 0.5]}, {τ, -10, +10}]
```

[image: convolution]

Then, the convolution I want to evaluate is:

```
Convolve[UnitStep[τ + 5] stripe[τ, 1] UnitStep[5 - τ], gaussian[τ, 0, 0.5], τ, x]
```

the result was 0, although it should not be 0.

I also tried to evaluate it via `Integrate`:

```
Integrate[stripe[τ, 1] gaussian[x - τ, 0, 0.5], {τ, -5, +5}]
```

the result was 0 again.

I don't know why the results were zero. Does the complication of the stripe function cause this problem? How can I evaluate it correctly?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That does not explain *why* your solution does not work (I'm pretty sure it is because of your definition of `stripe`), but if you replace `stripe` with:

```
stripe[x_, d_] := HeavisidePi[Mod[x/(2 d), 1]]
```

you get:

```
conv[x_] = Convolve[UnitStep[tau + 5] stripe[tau, 1] UnitStep[5 - tau],
     gaussian[tau, 0, 0.5], tau, x]

 (* -0.5 (1. Erf[2.82843 - 1.41421 x] + 1. Erf[5.65685 - 1.41421 x] + 
Erf[1.41421 (-5. + x)] + Erf[1.41421 (-3. + x)] + 
Erf[1.41421 (-1. + x)] - 1. Erf[1.41421 x] + 
Erf[1.41421 + 1.41421 x] - 1. Erf[2.82843 + 1.41421 x] + 
Erf[4.24264 + 1.41421 x] - 1. Erf[5.65685 + 1.41421 x]) *)


Plot[conv[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With `x` and `d` not numeric:

```
If[EvenQ[Quotient[x, d]], 1, 0]
(* 0 *)
```

The essential difficulty is using **programming** constructs `If` and `EvenQ` to formulate a **symbolic** analysis problem.

Comment: Since I used `SetDelayed`(:=) to define the stripe function, the right hand side must be evaluated for a specific `x` and `d` every time. In spite of this, why is it a problem?

Comment: @TaikiBessho No. If you want to define `stripe` only for numerical values, try `stripe[x_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := ...` in what case, `Convolve` does not return `0` (it just does not evaluate).

Comment: I understood the root of this problem is that both `Convolve` and `Integrate` try to evaluate it not numerically but analytically where `stripe[τ, 1]` is zero identically because `Quotient` remains unevaluated, `EvenQ` gives False and `If` returns 0. Is this what you wanted to say?

Comment: @anderstood Why does the `Convolve` remain unevaluated if we define the `stripe` numerically? Doesn't the built-in function `Convolve` take numerical functions as arguments?

Comment: @TaikiBessho `Convolve` works purely symbolically, essentially by calling `Integrate` to solve the convolution integral. This won't work for functions that only return values for numerical input (i.e. stay unevaluated for symbolic input), because `Integrate` can't do anything meaningful with those intransparent functions.